# How do you pronounce the name of the river Saône?

Tags: prononciation

I am thinking it is the same as the river Rhône, with the `a` effectively not changing anything. Is that correct?

Comment: http://fr.forvo.com/word/sa%C3%B4ne/

Comment: I looked on Forvo and it didn't come up! And now it does come up. WTF?

Comment: Oh....I searched for *soane* by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rh%C3%B4ne) and [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rh%C3%B4ne#Prononciation) indicate :

> Le Rhône (prononcé [ʁon] en français standard ou [ˈʁɔ.nə] en français régional)

and for [Saône](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%C3%B4ne) :

> La Saône [soːn]

So, it depends which prononciation you choose and what you call *not changing anything*.

There is the same [o] in the standard prononciation of *Rhône* but in *Saône*, it will be **elongated**.

I would not say it is the same personnally, but I am not an expert.

Comment: À ne pas manquer [ce pdf](http://lolita.unice.fr/~scheer/gghf/Pierret%2094%20-%20Phonetique%20historique%20du%20francais%20et%20notions%20de%20phonetique%20generale.pdf) au bas du lien pour Saône...

Comment: /o:/ and /o/ are just two ways to write out the same sound. /o/ in a closed syllable is always long (at least in conservative dialects), so a phonetic transcription may or may not include the length mark, since it's not contrastive.

Comment: @Eauquidort So, we could write *Rhône* prononciation [ʁon] or [ʁo:n] without difference?

Comment: Yes and no, we could write it out /ʁon/, /ʁo:n/, /ron/ or /ro:n/ without difference. Brackets are supposed to be used with close transcriptions, which record all the small individual and dialectal differences, plus details that don't matter in a given language (like the fact that /ʃ/ is pronounced with rounded lips [ʃʷ] in both French and English). [ʁon] and [soːn] is just an imprecision on the part of Wiktionary's editors.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed correct, *Saône* is pronounced `/son/`, meaning that the *a* is not pronounced and that the *ô* is pronounced like in *Rhône* as a *closed o*.

As usual, [Wiktionnaire reports the correct pronunciation for that word](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sa%C3%B4ne).

Comment: S'il est vrai que le *a* est bien muet, il faut cependant ajouter que la réalisation du son voyelle sera différent /selon les régions /ɔ / ou  /o/.

Comment: @Laure Certes, mais la prononciation avec /ɔ/ reste un régionalisme qui n'est pas la prononciation standard.

Comment: Un régionalisme est quelque chose de tout à fait « standard ». Chemin très glissant que de se lancer dans ce genre de définition à mon avis.  En tout état de cause, toute prononciation régionale est correcte,  donc dire que le wiktionnaire donne la prononciation correcte me semble un abus de langage.

Comment: La prononciation régionale est sans doute celle d'origine et donc celle dont découle la prononciation standard.

Comment: @YohannV. Les prononciations évoluent dans le temps et dans l'espace, il est difficile de parler d'**une** prononciation d'origine ou d'**une** prononciation régionale. On peut d'ailleurs noter que Sâone et Seine partagent la même étymologie (*sawk* + *onna*, rivière/fleuve sacré en gaulois) et que le « â » de Sâone a certainement été prononcé dans le passé.

Comment: @jlliagre Je suis d'accord, mais la racine étant la même, le nom a bien été donné **d'après** la prononciation régionale

Comment: Qui n'est donc ni la prononciation dite standard, ni l'une des autres prononciations régionales actuelles, le cas échéant…

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne suis pas sur de comprendre ton point de vue. Tu veux dire que comme dans la région, on ne parle plus gaulois, il est impossible d'avoir la prononciation origin{a/el}le?

Comment: Parler de prononciation régionale ou originale sans préciser l'époque, le lieu, voire la personne qui s'exprime est risqué. Même quelques représentations possibles pour Sâone comme [son], [so:n], [sɔn], [sɔ.nə] ne représentent pas toutes les variations réelles. Il existe une « infinité » de voyelles entre un o très fermé et un o très ouvert, sans compter des variations plus subtiles de ton et autres modulations. Il sera parfois possible de distinguer à l'oreille Sâone prononcé avec un fort accent lyonnais. Des diacritiques permettent d'affiner la représentation mais ont quand même des limites.